# How can I have a git pre-commit hook modify a file and include that file in the commit?

Tags: git, githooks

I have a pre-commit hook which modifies some files before they are committed; however when the hook runs, the files that it modifies do not get committed! How can I have the files included? I need this to work both for staged commits and unstaged "commit all modified files" commits, so I don't think staging the modified file will work here because that would exclude the original files in the latter case (since they are not staged).

Here's a simple reproduction case:

```
#!C:/Program\ Files/Git/usr/bin/sh.exe
echo "Test file" > testfile.txt
```

If I change a file and commit, the `testfile.txt` never gets committed; if I change a file, stage it, and commit, the same thing happens - `testfile.txt` is sitting there as a pending change.

Comment: Append `git add testfile.txt` to the hook.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithooks%5D+pre-commit+modify+files